# How to identify magento file names using "view page source"

Tags: magento-1.8, css

Please visit this link http://schoolboards4.newtrendzonline.com/ , after visiting the site, please see "view page source" of the site, In "view page source",
I want to edit the line number 121.

In which file, I have to edit the line 121 :

I am new to coding.

please help me in giving solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using a gala theme for Magento. According to

http://www.5180.es/5180/skin/frontend/default/galaelectronues/galaelectronues-theme-package/app/design/frontend/default/galaelectronues/template/page/html/em_head.phtml

The path is likely something like:

/app/design/frontend/default/XXXX/template/page/html/em_head.phtml

the XXXX may vary.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for reply, i will check it....

Comment: Hi, here menu is not displaying in http://schoolboards4.newtrendzonline.com/ , but displaying in http://demo.galathemes.com/gala-rainbow/index.php/?___store=default please give me solution  , Thanks in advance